# Get duration from a youtube url

Tags: youtube, meta

Im looking for a function that will pull the youtube duration of a video from the url. I read some tutorials but don't get it. I embed videos on my site using a url and I have a function that pulls the thumbnail and I just want something similar that gets the duration. Here's how I get the thumb...

```
function get_youtube_screen_link( $url = '', $type = 'default', $echo = true ) {
if( empty( $url ) )
    return false;

if( !isset( $type ) )
    $type = '';

$url = esc_url( $url );

preg_match("|[\\?&]v=([^&#]*)|",$url,$vid_id);

if( !isset( $vid_id[1] ) )
    return false;

$img_server_num =  'i'. rand(1,4);

switch( $type ) {
    case 'large':
        $img_link = "http://{$img_server_num}.ytimg.com/vi/{$vid_id[1]}/0.jpg";
        break;
    case 'first':
        // Thumbnail of the first frame
        $img_link = "http://{$img_server_num}.ytimg.com/vi/{$vid_id[1]}/1.jpg";
        break;
    case 'small':
        // Thumbnail of a later frame(i'm not sure how they determine this)
        $img_link = "http://{$img_server_num}.ytimg.com/vi/{$vid_id[1]}/2.jpg";
        break;
    case 'default':
    case '':
    default:
        $img_link = "http://{$img_server_num}.ytimg.com/vi/{$vid_id[1]}/default.jpg";
        break;
}
if( $echo )
    echo $img_link;
else
    return $img_link;
```

}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
<?php

    function getDuration($url){

        parse_str(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY),$arr);
        $video_id=$arr['v']; 


        $data=@file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$video_id.'?v=2&alt=jsonc');
        if (false===$data) return false;

        $obj=json_decode($data);

        return $obj->data->duration;
    }

    echo getDuration('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFQc7VRJowk');

?>
```

that returns the duration in seconds of the video.

Reference: http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html

You can use a function like [this one](http://www.laughing-buddha.net/php/sec2hms) to change the seconds to hours, minutes, and seconds.

Comment: I need the $video_id to to pull it from the url entered into a custom field for each post.

Comment: Updated the example to get the video_id from url

Comment: I used this as a function and it works but if a video has been removed from youtube then I get errors where it tries to output. How can I make an if statement to protect against that?

Comment: Updated the example to return false if video doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your time and workin me through that! Works perfectly.

Comment: This endpoint is no longer available, you have to use the youtube v3 api now.

Answer (score 5):

**youtube api v3**

---

**usage**

```
echo youtubeVideoDuration('video_url', 'your_api_key');
// output: 63 (seconds)
```

**function**

```
/**
* Return video duration in seconds.
* 
* @param $video_url
* @param $api_key
* @return integer|null
*/
function youtubeVideoDuration($video_url, $api_key) {

    // video id from url
    parse_str(parse_url($video_url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $get_parameters);
    $video_id = $get_parameters['v'];

    // video json data
    $json_result = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=$video_id&key=$api_key");
    $result = json_decode($json_result, true);

    // video duration data
    if (!count($result['items'])) {
        return null;
    }
    $duration_encoded = $result['items'][0]['contentDetails']['duration'];

    // duration
    $interval = new DateInterval($duration_encoded);
    $seconds = $interval->days * 86400 + $interval->h * 3600 + $interval->i * 60 + $interval->s;

    return $seconds;
}
```

Comment: doesn't work for me , says file_get_content is blocked for security reasons

Comment: **NOT** api_key, you should use "key".

Answer (score 4):

This is my function to get youtube duration in second.
he is fully 100% work.
you need just youtube id video and youtube api key.

how to add youtube api key show 
this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AQ9UamPN6E

```
public static function getYoutubeDuration($id)
    {



         $Youtube_KEY='';

         $dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id={$id}&key={$Youtube_KEY}");

         $vTime='';
         $H=0;
         $M=0;
         $S=0;

         $duration = json_decode($dur, true);
         foreach ($duration['items'] as $vidTime) {
         $vTime = $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration'];
         }

         $vTime = substr($vTime, 2);
         $exp = explode("H",$vTime);

         //if explode executed
         if( $exp[0] != $vTime )
         {
             $H = $exp[0];
             $vTime = $exp[1];
         }

         $exp = explode("M",$vTime);

         if( $exp[0] != $vTime )
         {
             $M = $exp[0];
             $vTime = $exp[1];
         }

         $exp = explode("S",$vTime);
         $S = $exp[0];


         $H = ($H*3600);
         $M = ($M*60);
         $S = ($H+$M+$S);


         return $S;

    }
```

This is my function to get youtube duration in second.
he is fully 100% work.
you need just youtube id video and youtube api key.

how to add youtube api key show 
this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AQ9UamPN6E

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a time formater to change the seconds into whatever format you like.
i.e. return gmdate("H:i:s", $obj->data->duration);

Answer (score 0):

```
function getYoutubeDuration($videoid) {
      $xml = simplexml_load_file('https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $videoid . '?v=2');
      $result = $xml->xpath('//yt:duration[@seconds]');
      $total_seconds = (int) $result[0]->attributes()->seconds;

      return $total_seconds;
}

//now call this pretty function. 
//As parameter I gave a video id to my function and bam!
echo getYoutubeDuration("y5nKxHn4yVA");
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You will need an API key. Go to https://developers.google.com/ and log in or create an account, if necessary. After logging in go to this link https://console.developers.google.com/project and click on the blue CREATE PROJECT button. Wait a moment as Google prepares your project.

2) You will need a web host that is running PHP with file_get_content supported. You can check by creating a new script with just "echo php_info();" and verifying that allow_url_fopen is set to On. If it is not, then change the configuration or talk to your web host.

```
<?php

  $sYouTubeApiKey = "<enter the key you get>";
  //Replace This With The Video ID. You can get it from the URL.
  //ie https://www.youtube.com/XWuUdJo9ubM would be
  $sVideoId = "XWuUdJo9ubM";

  //Get The Video Details From The API.
  function getVideoDetails ($sVideoId) {
    global $sYouTubeApiKey;
    //Generate The API URL
    $sUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$sVideoId."&key=".$sYouTubeApiKey."&part=contentDetails";
    //Perform The Request
    $sData = file_get_contents($sUrl);
    //Decode The JSON Response
    return json_decode($sData);
  }

  //Get The Video Duration In Seconds.
  function getVideoDuration ($sVideoId) {
    $oData = getVideoDetails($sVideoId);
    //Deal With No Videos In List
    if (count($oData->items) < 1) return false;
    //Get The First Video
    $oVideo = array_shift($oData->items);
    //Extract The Duration
    $sDuration = $oVideo->contentDetails->duration;
    //Use Regular Expression To Parse The Length
    $pFields = "'PT(?:([0-9]+)H)?(?:([0-9]+)M)?(?:([0-9]+)S)?'si";
    if (preg_match($pFields, $sDuration, $aMatch)) {
      //Add Up Hours, Minutes, and Seconds
      return $aMatch[1]*3600 + $aMatch[2]*60 + $aMatch[3];
    }
  }

  header("Content-Type: text/plain");
  $oData = getVideoDetails($sVideoId);
  print_r($oData);
  echo "Length: ".getVideoDuration($sVideoId);
?>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

##### An answer without using any Google API:

If you want the video length of a limited number of videos for a project, and you do not care about reliability (i.e., not to use in production), here is a simple and dirty Python-based web scraping solution that will not need any API key.

```py
import requests
def get_youtube_video_length_from_url(url: str = None):
    """
    Returns youtube video length in the format minute(s): seconds from the url
    """
    text = requests.get(url).text
    str_id = text.find("""<meta itemprop="duration""")
    return (
        text[str_id : str_id + 60]
        .split("content=")[1]
        .split(">")[0]
        .replace('"', "")
        .replace("PT", "")
        .replace("M", ":")
        .replace("S", "")
    )
```

Example:

```py
get_youtube_video_length_from_url("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ")

# 3:33
```

I get about one result per second with that solution, and I did not get a very fast IP ban (I could query more than 200 times without any ban).

Ps: It might work as long as youtube does not change the youtube web page's code. If so, you might need to modify the code.