# how to get description of youtube video details

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I have you tube video link:
            example:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EF5FnKTsIbc&feature=youtube_gdata_player
            i want to get   description and video title and image  of this link using php,how do it?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference

Comment: I'm suggesting you make an effort and come back with specific things you're having trouble with.

Comment: Youtube API V2.0 has been deprecated. You have to use V3 API.Which need API keys.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code, I tested it and works great.
Thanks for [IBM Developer network](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/)

You can see the entire code here.
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-youtubeapi/

---

### USAGE

```
// For the video >>> youtube.com/watch?v=37l11UzbvvA

// Video id = 37l11UzbvvA;

$vid="37l11UzbvvA";

// set video data feed URL

$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $vid;

// read feed into SimpleXML object

$entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

$video = parseVideoEntry($entry);

echo $video->title;
```

---

### Function > parseVideoEntry()

```
// function to parse a video <entry>
function parseVideoEntry($entry) {      
  $obj= new stdClass;

  // get author name and feed URL
  $obj->author = $entry->author->name;
  $obj->authorURL = $entry->author->uri;

  // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
  $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
  $obj->title = $media->group->title;
  $obj->description = $media->group->description;

  // get video player URL
  $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
  $obj->watchURL = $attrs['url']; 

  // get video thumbnail
  $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
  $obj->thumbnailURL = $attrs['url']; 

  // get <yt:duration> node for video length
  $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
  $obj->length = $attrs['seconds']; 

  // get <yt:stats> node for viewer statistics
  $yt = $entry->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
  $attrs = $yt->statistics->attributes();
  $obj->viewCount = $attrs['viewCount']; 

  // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
  $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
  if ($gd->rating) { 
    $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
    $obj->rating = $attrs['average']; 
  } else {
    $obj->rating = 0;         
  }

  // get <gd:comments> node for video comments
  $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
  if ($gd->comments->feedLink) { 
    $attrs = $gd->comments->feedLink->attributes();
    $obj->commentsURL = $attrs['href']; 
    $obj->commentsCount = $attrs['countHint']; 
  }

  // get feed URL for video responses
  $entry->registerXPathNamespace('feed', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
  $nodeset = $entry->xpath("feed:link[@rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/
  schemas/2007#video.responses']"); 
  if (count($nodeset) > 0) {
    $obj->responsesURL = $nodeset[0]['href'];      
  }

  // get feed URL for related videos
  $entry->registerXPathNamespace('feed', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
  $nodeset = $entry->xpath("feed:link[@rel='http://gdata.youtube.com/
  schemas/2007#video.related']"); 
  if (count($nodeset) > 0) {
    $obj->relatedURL = $nodeset[0]['href'];      
  }

  // return object to caller  
  return $obj;      
}
```

As Notified By ***Lothar*** Here is the Json Link, 
You can parse this JSON data easily using json_decode

> note: json_decode function works on PHP>=5.2.0

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/[VIDEO_ID]?v=2&alt=jsonc
```

For Example

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/37l11UzbvvA?v=2&alt=jsonc
```

Comment: After testing it found that using the JSON API simplies it a lot. See here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9167442/get-duration-from-a-youtube-url

Answer (score 2):

The code below is a direct copy-paste from a script of mine. Not sure if it still works. You can give it a shot.

```
<?php
$id = '38z8TPtT1BE';
$url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/$id?v=2&alt=json";
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
$output = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);  
print_r(json_decode($output));
?>
```

Youtube APIs documentation is your bible. You will get all that you want in there. The link is what @ceejayoz gave in the comments section.

PS: Welcome to SO, and next time you have any problem, put up what you have already done. People here would surely help you out.