# Getting load data about YouTube videos with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, analysis

I am writing a chrome extension that inserts JavaScript into webpages so that things such as load times can be analyzed (for troubleshooting purposes), and I was wondering if there is any way to gather data about youtube videos such as the size of the video, buffering speed, etc. using JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [Youtube APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/). You could at least retrieve the [length of the video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations#15605838). Apart from that, Buffer speed is most likely out of the scope of client side javascript. You'd have to resort to a [native application plugin](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi) for that.