# Problems with contentDetails YouTube API v3 Endpoint

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to see the duration of my videos but that value is not returned in my request to the `contentDetails` YouTube API endpoint.

Request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet,contentDetails&playlistId=PLzL9qQsHp57p-ncZezwjNIEe8fHS6Orkg&maxResults=1&key=[API_KEY]
```

Response:

```
"contentDetails": 
{

"videoId": "wZpteNGOoXs" -> where is the duration?

}
```

Comment: What if i told you to use ressource video and not playlistItems...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube API v3 , how to get video durations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations)

Comment: playlistitems do not include duration as well as a few other important data items for whatever reason. You'll have to make a call for video details if you want them.