# get YouTube video length returns wrong value

Tags: php, api, video, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using this function to get YouTube video length in seconds

```
function getDuration($url){
parse_str(parse_url($url,PHP_URL_QUERY),$arr);
$video_id=$arr['v'];
$data=@file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/'.$video_id.'?v=2&alt=jsonc');
if (false===$data) return false;
$obj=json_decode($data);
return $obj->data->duration;
}
```

But all videos return duration 236 like this video which its duration is 42 minutes and 45 seconds here's the sample

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/gXGn06tuvZM?v=2&alt=jsonc
```

is this something wrong with the function or with the youtube api as I noticed when I open youtube website all videos' duration has gone as in the image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The GData API has been retired, and will only return a "device not supported" video no matter what request you send (Which, I guess, is 236 seconds). You'll need to switch to V3 of the API.

Answer (score 0):

followed the steps hete to create a new app and get a new API key [google documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) then used this answer [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations#answer-15605838) then it was simple to split the duration into an array and retrieve values

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=9bZkp7q19f0&part=contentDetails
&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```