# How to get video from Youtube V3 using AJAX?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I know this question was asked many times at last time. I sought solution about it, but have not found. I suggest to do a good answer and attach this on first result position in search, that will be easy to find solution.

So, I use AJAX get request to get video from youtube server:

```
var url = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/54d@fj9?v=2&alt=jsonc';
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  //
});
```

But it gives me notice about changes API.
How I can do it step by step? For this need registration?

This answer: [Youtube API v3 , how to get video durations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations)
But where I can get youtube key?

Comment: I tried: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=_bWeZuPUZRA&key=AIzaSyCRDrvUf4V4IjumKoo5woctjWw_scJoJ74`

Comment: You get the YouTube key by registering your app at http://console.developers.google.com -- set a project name, go to the "APIs and Auth" menu to turn on the YouTube Data API, and then go to the "credentials" menu to create a public access API key.