# Get duration using YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I need to get the video duration using Youtube API V3. My application was working fine with API V3 but now it doesn't work.

I found a working example and it works:

```php
$dur = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&id=[VIDOID]&key=[API KEY]");


$duration =json_decode($dur, true);

foreach ($duration['items'] as $vidTime) {
    $vTime= $vidTime['contentDetails']['duration'];
}
```

Credits: [Youtube API v3 , how to get video durations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations)

This will return the time format something like this.

```
PT24M30S
```

How can I convent this to a readable time. Like 24:30?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible way is to use the function `str_replace();`

```
$stamp = "PT24M30S";
$formated_stamp = str_replace(array("PT","M","S"), array("",":",""),$stamp);

echo $formated_stamp; //should give "24:30"
```

**Bonus content - leading zeros**

In order to add leading zeros one must first split the string up with explode(), then format the numbers idividually with sprintf(); and finally add it all together again.

```
$exploded_string = explode(":",$formated_stamp);
$new_formated_stamp = sprintf("%02d", $exploded_string[0]).":".sprintf("%02d", $exploded_string[1]);
```

Comment: Just note this will convert `PT2M3S` to `2:3`

Answer (score 6):

I can't believe it, anyone have used [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php), why? It's just like this:

```
$duration = new DateInterval('PT24M30S');

print $duration->format('%H:%i:%s'); // outputs: 00:24:30
```

Helpful links:

- [The DateInterval class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php#class.dateinterval)
- [DateInterval::format](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: This is the best answer! If using laravel don't forget to import the class into the controller or whatever you are using it: `use DateInterval;`

Answer (score 1):

```
 $time_format = "PT24M30S ";

preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$time_format,$parts);

$hours = floor($parts[0][0]/60);
$minutes = $parts[0][0]%60;
$seconds = $parts[0][1];

echo $hours . ": ". $minutes .":". $seconds;
```

Answer (score 0):

[video resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) contains a `duration` field which is a `string` of the following format.    It will be up to you the developer to reformat it as necessary for your application and needs.

[contentDetails.duration](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.duration)

> The length of the video. The tag value is an ISO 8601 duration. For
>   example, for a video that is at least one minute long and less than
>   one hour long, the duration is in the format PT#M#S, in which the
>   letters PT indicate that the value specifies a period of time, and the
>   letters M and S refer to length in minutes and seconds, respectively.
>   The # characters preceding the M and S letters are both integers that
>   specify the number of minutes (or seconds) of the video. For example,
>   a value of PT15M33S indicates that the video is 15 minutes and 33
>   seconds long.
>
> If the video is at least one hour long, the duration is in the format
>   PT#H#M#S, in which the # preceding the letter H specifies the length
>   of the video in hours and all of the other details are the same as
>   described above. If the video is at least one day long, the letters P
>   and T are separated, and the value's format is P#DT#H#M#S. Please
>   refer to the ISO 8601 specification for complete details.

As to how to do it I would have to say remove the PT and the S and replace the M with a :. It will probably require some testing on your part depending on what happens when a value is null.  I would do some research into [ISO-8061](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

Answer (score 0):

I use the following function to convert the YouTube duration. Simply replace $yt with the format YouTube provided you and it'll print it out nice and readable.

```
function ConvertYoutubeVideoDuration($yt){
$yt=str_replace(['P','T'],'',$yt);
foreach(['D','H','M','S'] as $a){
    $pos=strpos($yt,$a);
    if($pos!==false) ${$a}=substr($yt,0,$pos); else { ${$a}=0; continue; }
    $yt=substr($yt,$pos+1);
}
if($D>0){
    $M=str_pad($M,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $S=str_pad($S,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return ($H+(24*$D)).":$M:$S"; // add days to hours
} elseif($H>0){
    $M=str_pad($M,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $S=str_pad($S,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return "$H:$M:$S";
} else {
    $S=str_pad($S,2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return "$M:$S";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution PHP**

```
function covtime($youtube_time){
            preg_match_all('/(\d+)/',$youtube_time,$parts);
            $hours = $parts[0][0];
            $minutes = $parts[0][1];
            $seconds = $parts[0][2];
            if($seconds != 0)
                return $hours.':'.$minutes.':'.$seconds;
            else
                return $hours.':'.$minutes;
        }
```