# Is it possible to get the duration (time) video through Youtube data API v3.0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is it possible to get the duration 
(time) video through Youtube data API v3.0. 
If so, how?

Comment: please refer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube API v3 , how to get video durations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to make a call to the Youtube Data API's Video resource after you make the search call.  You can put up to 50 video id's in search, so you wont have to call it for each element.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

You'll want to set part=contentDetails, because duration is there.

For example the following call:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=9bZkp7q19f0&part=contentDetails&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Gives this result:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XlbeM5oNbUofJuiuGi6IkumnZR8/ny1S4th-ku477VARrY_U4tIqcTw\"",
 "items": [
  {

   "id": "9bZkp7q19f0",
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"XlbeM5oNbUofJuiuGi6IkumnZR8/HN8ILnw-DBXyCcTsc7JG0z51BGg\"",
   "contentDetails": {
    "duration": "PT4M13S",
    "dimension": "2d",
    "definition": "hd",
    "caption": "false",
    "licensedContent": true,
    "regionRestriction": {
     "blocked": [
      "DE"
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

The time is formatted as an ISO 8601 string.  PT stands for Time Duration, 4M is 4 minutes, and 13S is 13 seconds.

Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations) question for more details

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it from .NET and C#.
First include the "contentDetails" part

```
var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Videos.List("snippet,contentDetails");
```

Second convert the duration to something more programmatically manageable as follows:

```
TimeSpan YouTubeDuration = System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToTimeSpan(searchResult.ContentDetails.Duration);
```

I hope this is helpful

Comment: Could you more explain please? What is the assembly file that have YoutubeService?

Answer (score 1):

using javascript

```js
function converTime(d) {
  //ignore the "PT" part
  d = d.search(/PT/i) > -1? d.slice(2) : d;
  let h, m, s;
  //indexes of the letters h, m, s in the duration
  let hIndex = d.search(/h/i),
      mIndex = d.search(/m/i),
      sIndex = d.search(/s/i);
  //is h, m, s inside the duration
  let dContainsH = hIndex > -1,
      dContainsM = mIndex > -1,
      dContainsS = sIndex > -1;
  //setting h, m, s
  h = dContainsH? d.slice(0, hIndex) + ":" : "";
  m = dContainsM? d.slice(dContainsH ? hIndex + 1 : 0, mIndex) : dContainsH? "0" : "0";
  s = dContainsS? d.slice(dContainsM ? mIndex + 1 : hIndex + 1, sIndex) : "0";
  //adding 0 before m or s
  s = (dContainsM || dContainsS) && s < 10? "0" + s: s;
  m = (dContainsH || dContainsM) && m < 10? "0" + m + ":" : m + ":";
  return d !== "0S" ? h + m + s : "LIVE"
}
console.log(converTime("PT6M7S"));
```