# How to calculate Youtube video duration via Jquery or Php code

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, youtube, youtube-api

I am working on project(in Codeigniter) where i need to calculate video duration which is running on my website but saved on You tube server. and how can i know that video is watched completely.

Comment: Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/youtube-api-v3-how-to-get-video-durations#answer-15605838) answer and also [link to YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) posted in same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `event.target.getDuration()` to calculate duration

`if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {` to know video is watched completely

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6x19930e/1/)