# Flask-based youtube playlist calculator giving null/incorrect output

Tags: python, flask, beautifulsoup

So, I'm creating a youtube playlist calculator whicxh takes the playlist URl as input from the user, this web-app is wtritten in Flask framework.
Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)

def calculate_playlist_length(playlist_url):
  html = requests.get(playlist_url).text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
  total_seconds = 0

  for span in soup.select('span.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer'):
      match = re.search(r'(\d+):(\d+)', span.text.strip())
      if match:
         minutes, seconds = match.groups()
         total_seconds += int(minutes) * 60 + int(seconds)

   hours = total_seconds // 3600
   minutes = (total_seconds % 3600) // 60
   seconds = total_seconds % 60

   return hours, minutes, seconds

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      playlist_url = request.form['playlist_url']
      hours, minutes, seconds = calculate_playlist_length(playlist_url)
      return render_template('result.html', hours=hours, minutes=minutes, 
        seconds=seconds)

    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
     app.run(debug=True)
```

But on running the app, which compiles succesfully and input a valid and public playlist. I get this output:

```
The total length of the playlist is 0:00:00.
```

How do I fix this? I have tried multiple URLs but the outuput is same. Also furthur down the line, I want to host this project on GCP and use YouTube APIs. So please guide me for that too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get video durations with YouTube API version 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596753/how-do-i-get-video-durations-with-youtube-api-version-3)

Answer (score 0):

YouTube playlist pages are [dynamic](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_web_scraping/python_web_scraping_dynamic_websites.htm), and if you preview the [source HTML](https://egghead.io/lessons/misc-chrome-devtools-elements-inspect-elements-vs-view-source) (which is all you get with *`requests.get(playlist_url).text`*) in the [network logs](https://support.happyfox.com/kb/article/882-accessing-the-browser-console-and-network-logs/) (it should be the first request if you refresh the page)<sup>([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtQEa.png))</sup>, then you'll see that pretty much everything is rendered with JavaScript.

Because of this, you can expect *`soup.select('span.ytd-thumbnail-overlay-time-status-renderer')`* to return an empty ResultSet.<sup>([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F6E25.png))</sup>

The good news is that the data you want *is* there in the source HTML, inside a `script` tag, from which various information can be extracted<sup>([view example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k12b9.png) with [this function](https://pastebin.com/UYJUqtXF))</sup>; so, if you alter `calculate_playlist_length` to something like

```py
def calculate_playlist_length(playlist_url):
    pSoup = BeautifulSoup((r:=requests.get(playlist_url)).content, 'html.parser') 
    rStatus = f'<Response [{r.status_code} {r.reason}]> from {r.url}'

    jScript = pSoup.select_one('script:-soup-contains("var ytInitialData")')
    try: 
        jData = json.loads(jScript.string.split('=',1)[-1].strip().rstrip(';'))
        
        keysList = [
            'contents', 'twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer', 'tabs', 0, 'tabRenderer',
            'content', 'sectionListRenderer', 'contents', 0, 'itemSectionRenderer',
            'contents', 0, 'playlistVideoListRenderer', 'contents'
        ]
        for k in keysList: jData = jData[k]
        vidLength = lambda v: int(v['playlistVideoRenderer'].get('lengthSeconds',0))

        total_seconds = sum([vidLength(vid) for vid in jData])
    except Exception as e: total_seconds, _ = 0, print(f'{rStatus}\n{e!r}') 
    return (total_seconds//3600), ((total_seconds%3600)//60), (total_seconds%60)
```

then `calculate_playlist_length(url)` should return <kbd>**`(0, 35, 46)`**</kbd> if `url` has been set to link [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5A4nPQbUF8CHsZzDMBFFOwHlMOun8vEU).